# Android Video doesn't work with all density

Tags: android-videoview, resolution

I have a problem with my application.

I have a video (mp4) in the raw folder and I try to lunch it in my activity.

I am making some density tests with the `AVD Manager`.

- hdpi (Android 7.1.1)    : KO
- mdpi (Android 7.1.1)    : KO
- xhdpi (Android 7.1.1)   : KO
- xxhdpi (Android 10)     : OK
- xxxhdpi (Android 7.1.1) : KO

**OK:** the video is lunching

**KO:** the video isn't but with no message.

I don't where the problem is :

- the video itself?
- the density?
- API?

```
final VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mouvement));
video.seekTo( 550 );
video.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        video.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: OK i confirm this is a API problem. If i use hdpi with android 10 the video is OK. But i still don't get it why ? Mp4 is supported since android 5.0 since the documentation...

Comment: Found the answer : use OntouchLsitener and not OnCLickListener

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer : use OntouchLsitener and not OnCLickListener